# Why are the black parts of my photos flashing?

Tags: troubleshooting, camera-controls, image-review

Recently I have borrowed my friend's SLR.

I don't know what settings I have changed.

When reviewing a photo, the black parts of the photo are highlighted (flashing) black/white every second.

The manufacturer of the camera is Olympus.

What is going on? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're in the mode of the camera where it shows you the over (or possibly under) exposed parts of your images.  Its a useful mode, but if you'd like to exit, click the up or down arrow while you see that image to cycle through the viewing modes.

Answer (score 4):

As rfusca said above, This is where parts of your picture has potential data loss due to exposure. This feature is called Zebra when looking it up in your User Manual.